# JavaScript OnChange select value into input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in my code that has some input fields and a select field.
The select field is populated by a table in a db, which also contains a clients name and e-mail.

When the select field is changed, it has to put the clients name and e-mail in the correct input fields. I have tried some ways, but haven't found the right one yet.

Here's my code:

```
    <table>
        <tr><td>Company</td><td>
        <select id="namelist" name="namelist" onchange="updateinput()">
        <?php 
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY ID");
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $value = $row1['Value'];
            $name = $row1['Name'];
            echo"<option value='$value'>$name<br>"; } ?>
        </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name of contact</td><td>
        <input required id="namecontact" name="namecontact" type="text" placeholder="Client name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>E-Mail contactpersoon</td><td>
        <input required id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Much thanks in advance**

Comment: From where the email id and name is coming?

Comment: You don't need AJAX and you don't need jQuery.  Please look up how to get and set the value of an HTML input, then you can easily write your function.  Also, you have a bug in your code - you never close the <option> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can store the email value using a `data-email` attribute in the `option` element, assuming the `name` is the text in the option then

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Company</td><td>
    <select id="namelist" name="namelist" onchange="updateinput()">
    <?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY ID");
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $value = $row1['Value'];
        $name = $row1['Name'];
        $email = $row1['Email'];
        echo"<option data-email='' value='$value'>$name<br>"; } ?>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name of contact</td><td>
    <input required id="namecontact" name="namecontact" type="text" placeholder="Client name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>E-Mail contactpersoon</td><td>
    <input required id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"></td></tr>
</table>
```

then you can have a change event handler for the select

```
var namelist = document.getElementById('namelist');
namelist.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var option = namelist.options[namelist.selectedIndex];
  document.getElementById('namecontact').value = option.value;
  document.getElementById('email').value = option.dataset.email;
});
```

Comment: This is what I needed, so much thanks, you helped me out. I combined your answer Rayon's answer to make it clear to me how this works

Answer (score 3):

Keep email and name of the client in `data-*` attributes so that you can retrieve those values on `onchange` event.

> [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string)

Try this:

```js
function updateinput(e) {
  var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
  document.getElementById('namecontact').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-name');
  document.getElementById('email').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-email');

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>
      <select id="namelist" name="namelist" onchange="updateinput(this)">
        <option>Select data</option>
        <option data-email='abc1@abc.com' data-name='abc1 xyz' value='test'>test1</option>

        <option data-email='abc2@abc.com' data-name='abc2 xyz' value='test'>test2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name of contact</td>
    <td>
      <input required id="namecontact" name="namecontact" type="text" placeholder="Client name">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail contactpersoon</td>
    <td>
      <input required id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/g12au79z/)

Comment: Much thanks. your answer combined with Arun P's answer was the solution for me getting how to do this!